# ConcurrentModificationException thrown in a multithreaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, synchronization, locking

I am trying to make a simulation of a program which simulates different threads removing and adding objects in an ArrayList. However, late in the simulation I get concurrentModificationExceptions (when the threads are trying to access and modify the same variable while an iterator is being used to iterate through the data). I have searched it up and seen some topics about this saying that I needed to use locks/synchronization and/or using ListIterators instead of enhanced for-loops, however, none of these options seemed to fix the problem. Here is what I have tried to do so far:

```
public Object removeSomething1(){
    synchronized(this){ //Also tried only putting it around the remove block
        for(Object o : myList){
            myList.remove(o);
            return o;
        }
    }

}

//This is another variaton which did not yield any improved result

public Object removeSomething2(){
    ListIterator<Object> iter = myList.listIterator();
        While(iter.hasNext()){
            Object s = iter.next();
            synchronized(this){
                iter.remove();

            }
            return s;

        }

    }

//After some request here is also the simple code which adds to the list

public addSomething(Object o){
    myList.add(o);
}
```

I execute 5 threads which calls upon these methods in their run() method in an interval of 500ms (using Thread.sleep()). If I increase the sleep timer in each thread and put a Thread.sleep() between each instanciation of threads, the problem seems to go away, but I want the threads to run at (closely) the same time without them interfering with the iterator at the same time which envokes the ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Instead of `for (Object o : myList) myList.remove(o);` why not just have `myList.removeAll()` ?

Comment: Because I do not want to remove all objects. I want each thread to remove  its own object. This is just a sample code of a greater and more substantial program where each thread adds and thereafter removes the object it added, but as stated, the Exception is only thrown in the "remove-section" of the code.

Comment: @tomSurge can you show all code that is modifying the list? What is adding to the list and how? By the way, what you have posted does not even compile.

Comment: Please don't post code that I can see won't compile and tell me it compiles. If you copy what you have there into a source file, there is no way it will compile, because not every path through the method leads to a `return` statement.

Comment: It will be something like "cannot resolve symbol o" for the first method and "missing return statement" for the second method. What about the code that adds to the list?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I added the method now.

Comment: 1. Your both "loops" that "remove elements" can be simplified to `list.remove(0)`. I have no idea what you are actually trying to achieve there, because none of them compiles. 2. All modifications of the list have to be synchronised, your `add` is not.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll need to move the `synchronized` block to contain all of `removeSomething2()`. You _must_ synchronize the entire iteration.

Comment: That simple answer seemed to fix my problem! Thank-you! @LouisWasserman

Answer (score -2):

After a suggestion from the user Louis Wasserman, I move the `synchronized` block to contain all of removeSomething2(). This makes sense as it now only let's one thread do the whole iteration at a time. This is how the solution looks:

```
public Object removeSomething2(){
synchronized(this){
    ListIterator<Object> iter = myList.listIterator();
        While(iter.hasNext()){
            Object s = iter.next();
            iter.remove();
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This all code is equivalent to `myList.remove(0);`... And instead of having entire method body in synchronized block on `this`, you could just make the method synchronized... And finally, it is not a solution to the problem you have described, if you are adding and removing items to/from the list on multiple threads, while you adds are still not synchronized...

Comment: Also, still definitely won't compile.